# Facebook posts via some app in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, slcomposeviewcontroller

I am using `SLComposeViewController` framework to create Facebook connectivity through iPhone app, to post feeds from my app to Facebook.

However, i want to use a particular account for e.g. `myCompanyName` account to post on Facebook. It will be like following:

*Click on post to Facebook button -> myCompanyName account will be like an intermediate account and on its wall my posts will be displayed -> Once done post data to user's personal fb account.*

So whenever user will see post on his wall, he will see posted via "`myCompanyName`".

How do i do this?

Right now I am posting directly to user's wall using follwing code:

```
  SLComposeViewController *controllerSLC = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

  [controllerSLC addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:someurl]];

  [controllerSLC addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someimg.png"]];

  [self presentViewController:controllerSLC animated:YES completion:Nil];
```

Please help.

Comment: can you show current codes ?

Comment: Please have a look at my edited question

Answer (score 2):

Try this code...

```
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", nil];

    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                                      /* handle success + failure in block */
                                  }];
    NSString *appId = @"4154637324343248";
NSString *msg = @"Hello World! This is my first post from my app";
    NSString *senderName = @"XXXXX";
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   appId, @"api_Key",
                                   msg, @"Message",
                                   senderName, @"Name",
                                   nil];
    [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

Before to run this you need configure your facebook account with the device built in app in Settings, if not facebook login page will be displayed

Comment: Following error is displayed:  No known class method for selector 'openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:'

Comment: Go to developer.facebook.com and register yourself as a developer and download facebook latest sdk, import it in to your project #import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>, also you can get AppId there.

Comment: Integrating to native ios apps >> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/